# Rails 5: search by keyword and sort by distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a search form on my app:

```
<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label "Search for" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "search", name: nil  %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

that searches by distance:

```
  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @las = La.near(action,10).reorder('distance')
    else
      @las = []
    end
  end
```

The results are sorted by distance and all works well up to here!! The only issue here is that the results do not appear according to the keyword typed as well. Thus whatever keyword I type, all results appear and sorted by distance.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the content of `params[:search]` within the `near` scope:

```
@items = Item.near(params[:search], 10).reorder('distance')
```

Comment: I got it to work with this: `@items = Item.search(params[:search]).near(action,10).reorder('distance')` But I still want the results to be found according to the full keyword typed!! Any ideas how I can do that??

Comment: I don't really know what's `near`, are you using some gem you haven't mentioned?

Comment: It's from Geocoder gem. https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder